# Undefined index - upload de audio

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

Estou com um pequeno código para fazer upload de áudio, porém está apresentando erro de Undefined index em duas linhas referentes a "audioFile".

> Notice: Undefined index: audioFile in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\upload.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: audioFile in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\upload.php on line 6

Encontrei diversas perguntas similares mas não consegui solucionar o problema. Nestas perguntas consultadas, na maioria das vezes o problema estava na declaração do "enctype", o que acredito não ser o meu caso.

Segue o código:

**formulario.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Upload de audio</title>
</head>

<body>
     
    <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="audioFile"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Audio" name="save_audio"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save_audio']) && $_POST['save_audio'] == "Upload Audio")
{
    $dir='uploads/';
    $audio_path=$dir.basename($_FILES['audioFile']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audioFile']['tmp_name'],$audio_path))
    {
        echo 'upload ok';
    }
}
?>
```

> **Obs.:** A pasta uploads encontra-se no mesmo caminho que as páginas aqui apresentadas.

Comment: O código de exemplo que colocou a mim funcionou me na perfeição. Atenção no entanto ao tamanho do ficheiro enviado, este não pode ser maior que o `upload_max_filesize` definido no `php.ini`, que por defeito costuma ser `2M`

Comment: Também achei que fosse o arquivo e testei com arquivos diferentes, um deles possui 1,4Mb e também não foi. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Você marcou a tag `wordpress` - esse arquivo `upload.php` está dentro do seu tema?

Comment: Está fora do tema. Estas páginas que estou testando estão em um diretório anterior aos temas C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs. Sendo que o tema está em C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes